# Bucle for anidado a List Comprehension

Tags: python, django

estoy trabajando con Django, tengo una aplicación que es un blog, y en las vistas de esa aplicación, la función que recupera los posts. Bien, los posts tienen un campo 'categoria', que es un ManyToManyField al modelo 'Category'.

La función de mi vista es la siguiente:

```
def blog(request):
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
categories = []
for post in posts:
    for category in post.categoria.all():
        categories.append(category.nombre)

categories = list(dict.fromkeys(categories))

return render(request, 'BlogApp/blog.html', {
    'posts': posts,
    'categories': categories,
})
```

Esto funciona, pero estoy intentando eliminar el bucle for anidado y utilizar List Comprehension, pero no me funciona. Lo que he intentado ha sido lo siguiente:

```
categories = [category.nombre for category in post.categoria.all() for post in posts]
```

Los modelos son los siguientes:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Name',
        max_length=50
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Post(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Title',
        max_length=50
    )
    contenido = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Content',
        max_length=10000,
    )
    imagen = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='Image',
        upload_to='blogapp',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    autor = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name='Author',
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(
        verbose_name='Category',
        to=Category,
    )
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Gracias.

Comment: El orden de los `for` dentro de la list comprehension está al revés. Como regla mnemotécnica, recuerda que deben aparecer en el mismo orden dentro de la comprehension en el que aparecerían con bucles for anidados "normales". Por tanto sería `[category.nombre for post in posts for category in post.categoria.all()]`. A mi también me resulta contraintuitivo :-)

Comment: Hola abulafia, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha quedado del todo claro. El problema es que los ejemplos que veía eran más simples, con números y ranges, y no me terminaba de aclarar, pero sabiendo lo que me has dicho, me queda claro. Muchísimas gracias.